# Focus into a newly replaced text field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to replace the HTML of a text field when it gets focus. My code looks like this:

```
<div id="my_field">
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, :value => "Enter Name" %>
</div>
```

My jQuery used to replace the HTML inside my_field:

```
$("#my_field")
    .delegate('#my_field input', 'focus', function(e){
        if($(this).attr('type') == 'text'){
            $(this).parent().html('<input type="text" value="" name="..." id="name">');
        }
    });
```

Just after replacing the HTML, the newly created text box does not get the focus. What should I do to get the cursor on the text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually focus the new `input`, using the no-args overload of [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus) :

```
$("#my_field")
    .delegate('#my_field input', 'focus', function(e){
        if($(this).attr('type') == 'text'){
            $(this).parent().html('<input type="text" value="" name="..." id="name">');
            $("#name").focus();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#my_field")
.delegate('#my_field input', 'focus', function(e){
    if($(this).attr('type') == 'text'){
        $(this).parent().html('<input type="text" value="" name="..." id="name">');
    }
    $("#name").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('<input type="text" value="" name="..." id="name">').appendTo('selector').focus()
```